# jq to merge two files with different formats

Tags: jq

I have two files

`file 1`

```
{
    "version": "2",
    "run_id": "1",
    "crn": "crn",
    "date": "2022-11-02T02:09:30.629Z",
    "evidences": [
        {
            "version": "2",
            "id": "2d"
        },
        {
            "version": "2",
            "id": "3e"
        }  
]
```

`file 2`

```
[
        {
            "version": "3",
            "id": "3d"
        },
        {
            "version": "2",
            "id": "3f"
        }    
]
```

can we use `jq` to merge contents from `file 2` into `evidences` section of `file 1`? which the result should like below

`file 1`

```
{
    "version": "2",
    "run_id": "1",
    "crn": "crn",
    "date": "2022-11-02T02:09:30.629Z",
    "evidences": [
        {
            "version": "2",
            "id": "2d"
        },
        {
            "version": "2",
            "id": "3e"
        },
        {
            "version": "3",
            "id": "3d"
        },
        {
            "version": "2",
            "id": "3f"
        }    
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is `+=` to add up arrays while retaining the context, and `input` to access the second file:

```bash
jq '.evidences += input' file1.json file2.json
```

```json
{
  "version": "2",
  "run_id": "1",
  "crn": "crn",
  "date": "2022-11-02T02:09:30.629Z",
  "evidences": [
    {
      "version": "2",
      "id": "2d"
    },
    {
      "version": "2",
      "id": "3e"
    },
    {
      "version": "3",
      "id": "3d"
    },
    {
      "version": "2",
      "id": "3f"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bGPUwiQJFyw)

Comment: Similar: `jq --slurpfile f2 file2.json '.evidences += $f2[0]' file1.json`